# Problem while compiling friggeri CV template with: ' fontspec error: "font-not-found"'

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, friggeri-cv

I have somme problem while I'm trying to compile template CV from: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv .
I have install texlive-full package on Ubuntu and tryied to compiled this template with command: lualatex cv_10.tex 
And I get:

```
: /home/lgadawski/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "HelveticaNeue" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.53 \newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
```

I have also trying to do this on Windows with MikTex with same result. I spent some hours but couldn't find explanation why is that and how could I properly compile it and built my own CV.

Regards!

Comment: [welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/PiJ21)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That template assumes you have obtained a license for Linotype's [Neue Helvetica](http://www.linotype.com/1266/NeueHelvetica-family.html?site=valuepacks&format=ot-cff&branding=pro) (€45 to €1500) and properly installed the font. If you haven't, try `{Arial}`, `{TeX Gyre Heros}`, or whatever you like, instead. Locate `friggeri-cv.cls` and modify the following lines (l. 53--58):

```
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Light}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Nils. Do U know some similar fonts like Helvetica UltraLight or Light? Becouse Arial unfortunately doesn't have such faces.. And another question is why on Windows with MikTex I can successfully compile it when I change lines that U adviced, but on Ubuntu I can't, and get the same error like erlier with Helvetica? Thanks Again!

Comment: @LukaszGadawski -- A regular Ubuntu installation is unlikely to have Arial installed by default.  Do you have such a font installed? (Try: `fc-list | grep -i arial`)  Alternatively, did you try it with TeX Gyre Heros? I believe it can be installed with `apt-get install tex-gyre`.

Comment: Perhaps a suitable free replacement font would be [Source Sans Pro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcesans.adobe/) by Adobe.  When I installed it, I got black, bold, semibold, regular, light, and extralight fonts, which should be able to replace the 'ultralight' and 'condensed bold' of Helvetica.

Comment: @Jon -- Adobe Sans Pro is very nice, thank U.

Comment: @Jon How did you guys install Adobe Sans Pro? I'm using Windows 7 and I don't find how to install this font.

Comment: @Kalissar -- I'm afraid the last version of Windows I used was XP, many years ago.  What I remember from back then, was something like this: download [the fonts in question](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcesans.adobe/); unpack the archive (the `.zip` file); copy the files to the 'fonts' (?) directory, which can be found in the 'control panel'.  I wish I could be more help, but I imagine more precise advice can be found on the web for how to install new fonts in general (and thus, these ones as well).

Comment: Source Sans is included in TeXLive. `tlmgr install sourcesanspro.`

Comment: that said -- when using Lua/XeLaTeX, it's  sufficient to just copy the .otf files from the zip file @jon mentioned to your global font directory (c:\windows\fonts or similar), same procedure as with any other font. No need to install that TeX package.

Comment: @jon You have answered the question in the comments! Can you post `Source Sans Pro` as an answer and I'll upvote it?

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: It is also possible to use the simplified version of the Friggeri CV from my [github account](https://github.com/eklenske/CV). I modified the template so that it works with a regular Texlive installation and `pdflatex`, without the need for `luatex` and `biber`.

Answer (score 2):

(As requested.)

One alternative might be [Source Sans Pro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcesans.adobe/) by Adobe, which gave me the following fonts:

```
SourceSansPro-BlackIt.otf       SourceSansPro-It.otf
SourceSansPro-Black.otf         SourceSansPro-LightIt.otf
SourceSansPro-BoldIt.otf        SourceSansPro-Light.otf
SourceSansPro-Bold.otf          SourceSansPro-Regular.otf
SourceSansPro-ExtraLightIt.otf  SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt.otf
SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.otf    SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf
```

Which should include enough variations to replace the Helvetica-Neue fonts.  I suppose you'd want to use the `-Black.otf` version for Condensed Bold, `-ExtraLight.oft` for the Ultralight, and so on.

In terms of installing them, under GNU/Linux, I simply added them to my `~/.fonts` directory.  On Windows, my comment suggested this might be accomplished by moving the files to the 'Fonts' folder in the 'Control Panel' --- but that is a hazy memory from Windows XP days.  (Please correct me if I'm mistaken.)  Macs must have a personal fonts folder, too, but as to where that might be....

**But** nowadays, you can install Source Sans Pro directly from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sourcesanspro), and then use (if so inclined) via `\usepackage{sourcesanspro}`.  This is much easier in general, but I'd be inclined in this case to make the substitutions directly.

Comment: @LondonRob -- I posted an answer; I hope this is what you meant!

Answer (score 0):

... so after installing  Source Sans Pro,modify `friggeri-cv.cls` as follows:

```
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{SourceSansPro}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{SourceSansPro ExtraLight}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{SourceSansPro Black}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{SourceSansPro Light}
```

Comment: Don't modify class files, do the changes in the document preamble.