# Friggeri resume - Very different rendering in different readers

Tags: xetex, pdf, viewers, resume

I wrote my CV using the Friggeri resume template, but I just noticed a problem: the document it's rendered very differently between Acrobat Reader and FoxIt PDF Reader and Document Viewer:

[image: The document as displayed on FoxIt and Document Viewer]

[image: The document as displayed on Adobe Acrobat]

I used xelatex and the icons are symbols from FontAwesome, following this tutorial: https://coderwall.com/p/r67dyq where I defined a new fontawesome.sty.
Also I changed the in the friggeri-cv.cls the colorcounter function to get only the first letter coloured:

```
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        brown\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}
```

I call the icons on the sections as: `\section{{\FA \faStar} Expertise}`

**Here is my code of the resume, reduced at the essential:**

```
    \documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} 
    % \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \usepackage{fontawesome}

    \definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.55}
    \definecolor{skype}{HTML}{12A5F4}
    \definecolor{html5}{HTML}{e34c26}
    \definecolor{php}{HTML}{6c7eb7}
    \definecolor{db}{HTML}{FF9900}
    \definecolor{linkedin}{HTML}{1683BB}


    \setmathfont{STIXGeneral}
    % \addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

    \begin{document}
    \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
    \header{Kiker}{Surname}{Front End Web Developer} % Your name and current job title/field

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   SIDEBAR SECTION
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
    \section{contact}
    {\color{light-gray}{\FA \faHome}}
    {\color{skype}{\FA \faSkype}} \href{skype:myskype.myskype?call}{myskype.myskype}
    {\color{light-gray}{\FA \faEnvelope}} \href{mailto:myemail@gmail.com}{myemail@gmail.com}
    ~
    {\color{html5}{\FA \faFire}} \href{http://www.mywebsite.de}{Portfolio}
    {\color{gray}{\FA \faPencil}} \href{http://www.myblog.net}{My Blog}
    {\color{linkedin}{\FA \faLinkedin}} \href{http://au.linkedin.com/pub/}{LinkedIn}
    {\color{gray}{\FA \faGithubSign}} \href{https://github.com/}{GitHub}
    \section{programming}
    \small{{\color{red} \FA \faHeart} JavaScript, jQuery,
    {\color{html5}\FA \faHtml5} HTML5, CSS3,
    {\color{php}\FA \faCode} PHP, Groovy/Grails,
    {\color{gray}\FA \faLinux} Linux, LEMP, NGINX,
    {\color{db}\FA \faTh} MySQL, Amazon AWS}
     \section{languages}
     \emph{proficient} English
     \emph{mother tongue} Italian
     \emph{notions} Spanish \& French
    \end{aside}

    \section{{\FA \faUser} About me}

    \section{{\FA \faStar} Expertise}

    \textbf{Professional Capabilities}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item{High-quality front-end development for web sites and applications}
        \item{Modular, DRY, robust and reusable code}
        \item{Performance optimization, progressive enhancement, usability}
        \item{SEO with semantic HTML, Micro Formats and schema.org structures}
        \item{Site planning}
        \item{User interface design}
    \end{itemize}

    \textbf{Technical Skills}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item{Scalable HTML and CSS}
        \item{JavaScript Development (includes advanced jQuery and plugins development, HTML5 API, vanilla JavaScript)}
        \item{Responsive Web Design}
        \item{Mobile development (in browser)}
        \item{Experience with Linux environments.}
        \item{Working knowledge of PHP, using: CodeIgniter, ExpressionEngine, WordPress}
        \item{Experience with Groovy/Grails}
        \item{Working experience with software versioning, in particular Git and Mercurial}
        \item{CSS Preprocessor (SASS, SCSS and LESS)}
    \end{itemize}

    \clearpage
    \section{{\FA \faSuitCase} Experience}

    \section{{\FA \faBook} Education}

    \begin{entrylist}

    \entry
    {2004--2010}
    {Degree in {\normalfont Computer Science and Automation Engineering}}
    {Polytechnic Marche University, Italy}
    {  }

    \end{entrylist}


    \section{{\FA \faQuote} Recommandations}


    \end{document}
```

** This is how the fontawesome.sty looks like:**
*I have the fontawesome font installed on my system*

```
\def\faUserMd{\symbol{"F200}}

\def\faLinux{\symbol{"F17C}}
\def\faHtml5{\symbol{"F13B}}
\def\faCode{\symbol{"F121}}
\def\faQuote{\symbol{"F10D}}
\def\faSuitCase{\symbol{"F0F2}}
```

Comment: If you can get your hands on the code, that would help ;)

Comment: Using Adobe Reader X and Foxit Reader on [the example `CV.pdf`](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv/blob/master/cv.pdf) it all looks good (but only the heart symbol is used). We definitely need more information on this one: a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and at least a link to the symbols/font would been helpful.

Comment: I added a bit to the description, I hope that helps.

Comment: @Kicker: I guess we really need a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), that is, a complete and compilable piece of code (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I added a minimum working example, the fontawesome font is installed in my system.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't complie your MWE because I don't have the helvetica neue font installed on my system. Anyway try to further reduce you not-so-MWE: can you still reproduce the problem removing all the text between `\header{Kiker}` and `\end{document}` and leaving just `\section{{\FA \faStar} Expertise}`?

Comment: I will try again removing any text in between and to check what can cause the issue to help understanding that better. There is anything else I can try for that?

Comment: @Kicker Skype icon is not working.

Comment: Did you find a solution with this issue? I got the same problem.

Comment: No I haven't found a solution for this to work. I have even tried to print out a Foxit.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem while trying to achieve exactly the same thing as you with the Friggeri template. This problem comes from a bug with the pdf engine of XeLaTex with OTF font file format when it is at a particular resolution as discussed in http://typophile.com/node/46451.

As a workaround, you can use the .ttf version of the font. To do this, download the latest FontAwesome package at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/. Then extract the content and copy the file named "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" in a sub-folder named "fonts" in your LaTex document's location. Then, the font can be loaded and used in LaTex manually like this for example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\FA}[Path = fonts/]{fontawesome-webfont}

\def\faLinux{{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}}
\def\faSE{{\FA\symbol{"F18D}}}
\def\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\def\github{{\FA\symbol{"F092}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Linux icon: \faLinux \\
StackExchange icon: \faSE \\
GitHub icon: \github \\
Skype icon: \faSkype

\end{document}
```

Which is supposed to yield to:

[image]

Everything seems to work fine so far for me. You can take a look at my [GitHub](https://github.com/jnsebgosselin/Curriculum-Vitae) where I exactly did this with the Friggeri-cv template. I am working in the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS environment.

Comment: Oh yeah, have also to give credit to this thread http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134121 for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried to reproduce your error, but I couldn't.
I run this simplified code:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113912/17151
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Source Sans Pro}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Source Sans Pro Light}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Source Sans Pro Semibold}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Source Sans Pro}
\setmathfont{STIXGeneral}

\begin{document}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
\header{Name}{Surname}{Front End Web Developer}
    \begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
    \section{contact}
    {\color{gray}{\FA \faHome}}
    {\color{gray}{\FA \faEnvelope}} \href{mailto:myemail@gmail.com}{email@mail.com}
    \end{aside}

\section{{\FA \faUser} About me}
{\color{magenta}{\FA \faHeart}}~%
{\color{yellow}{\FA \faStar}}~some text
\end{document}
```

and get these results with different pdf viewers:

**Adobe Reader XI**

[image: Adobe image here]

**Foxit Reader 6.0.5**

[image: Foxit image here]

**Sumatra PDF 2.3.2**

[image: Sumatra image here]

I can't see any differencies. I link you [my pdf output](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzguJ6p9_nxlY0RoY0JWUER0bVE/edit?usp=sharing) (I hope it works) so you can test it on your system.

Comment: I just tried, but unfortunately I get the same issue. I also tried different font families, Ubuntu and Arial. I already have Helvetica installed on my system. Maybe it could be because of how the fonts are installed on my system? For example if I specify as font Ubuntu Regular, I get an alert since looks like the font is not installed, while just Ubuntu works properly. I had the same issue with the original Helvetica as specified on Friggeri.cls where I changed {Helvetica Neue} to just {Helvetica}.

Comment: Can you see the same behaviour with my pdf (linked in the answer)?

Comment: Your pdf output works properly for me, I don't have the issue, that is what makes me think about the installed font issue.

Comment: I suggest you to try with Adobe Source Sans Pro as showed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113912/17151.

Comment: Ok I try with Source Sans Pro. I am wondering if there is any particular way to install TTFs/OTFs fonts under Ubuntu. I usually copy the font files under /usr/local/share/fonts/truetype and then  I run: sudo fc-cache -f -v

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18357/how-to-install-otf-fonts) can help.

Comment: @Kicker -- a personal font folder for Debian/Ubuntu is `~/.fonts`.  Nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks @jon the problem of the font was because he didn't have the helvetica on his system and because to compile that particular pdf I had to install FontAwesome on my system.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the PDF in Illustrator and outline everything you won't have output issues anymore, not really a fix, more like a hack.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)