# fontawesome icons are getting too big using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, mac, fontawesome

The following example must be compiled with XeLaTeX to reproduce the issue.

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
Text Text \faMobilePhone\ Text Text
\end{document}
```

Normally I am using TeXworks to compile and view the output. With the internal viewer I am getting the desired result. The following image demonstrates it:

[image]

However if I open the pdf with Preview (viewer of Mac) the scaling of the icon fails.

[image]

If I open the pdf file with Adobe Acrobat Reader the icon is still scaled correctly. If I print the page my printer is also not able to scale the icons correctly.

If I use LuaLaTeX everything seems to work correctly.

*Can you reproduce the issue and do you know a solution?*

Comment: Confirmed; seems to be a problem with the PDF engine on Mac OS X. If opened with Adobe Reader the size is correct; both it and the internal viewer of TeXworks don't rely on the PDF toolkit of Mac OS X.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for your replay. I couldn't find any related issue and I thought it was my flaw ;-).

Comment: Is it a CFF-flavoured OpenType font (usually with a `.otf` extension) with a non-1000 UPM? If yes, then it is a [known bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/23/).

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Interesting. I am not enough familiar with fonts to know whether it's a non 1000 upm or not. But the bug seems to be similar. Thanks.

Comment: The `.otf` file available from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/, do indeed have a 1792 UPM size, so that is the bug. The only immediate solution is to convert the font to 1000 UPM units (using FontForge or similar).

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Maybe you can write this as an answer. I think it's the best approach so far.

Comment: Under the Windows system and MiKTeX I have no problem. Alos, just in case: did you try with the latest version of the font? The package installs version 3.1.1 and latest is 4.2.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`xdvipdfmx` (XeTeX’s output driver) has a bug with handling CFF-flavoured OpenType fonts (fonts usually with a `.otf` extension) with non-1000 UPM. It is a [known bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/23/) with no known fix, unfortunately.

The Font Awesome has a 1792 UPM, so it suffers from this bugs.

One possible work around is to change the font to use 1000 UPM. [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/) can do this easily, from the GUI **Element → Font Info → General → Em Size** and change the value to 1000 while keeping the **[x] Scale Outlines** selected, so that FontForge can do the necessary scaling to compensate for the UPM change. Then generate a new OTF file. Using FontForge’s Python scripting, this can be done as:

```python
import fontforge
font = fontforge.open("FontAwesome.otf")
font.em = 1000
font.generate("FontAwesome-1000upm.otf")
```

Another solution is to just use the TTF version of the font, but I’m not sure how compatible is it with the OTF version encoding-wise.

Comment: I'm facing the same trouble and, as I didn't succeed to generate the `FontAwesome-1000upm.otf` file, is it possible for you to make it available for download? BTW, what is then necessary (and sufficient)? Just to replace `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` by `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome-1000upm}` in the `fontawesome.sty` file?

Answer (score 7):

Download https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip

then under fonts, install ttf instead of otf and in your `*.sty` file replace

```
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome} with \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome Regular}
```

Comment: While I don't doubt that this answer works, could you explain why it does?

Comment: thanks a lot! 
Just wanted to point out, that this solution also solved the "inverse problem" (wrong scaling in Adobe Reader; correct scaling in every other reader I tried)