# How do I make Portable Document Format -- portable?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdf, adobe, fontawesome

I prepared a document in XeLaTeX in Linux, fonts embedded, then I went to a printing guy on windows + lots of Adobe tools, and pdf looks the other way on his machine: some fonts get scaled which results in a slightly deformed layout.

How do You get a portable pdf?

My first thought is to convert pdf to ps with a virtual printer (CUPS in case of linux).

One other possible solution is to embed fonts in the ps resulted:

```
ps2pdf14 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress document.ps
```

**Edit**:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\faBullhorn test.

\end{document}
```

In okular:

[image]

In Adobe Reader:

[image]

You see in Adobe the glyph is larger. How do I process pdf so that it is displayed in the same way in any major pdf viewer?

**Edit 2**:

The problem with scaled font is solved if I open the pdf and export it to pdf with [Master PDF Editor](http://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor.php) -- but its free version warns me about the watermark (which I actually can't find).

Export to pdf in [PDF Shuffler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/) doesn't help.

Printing to pdf in virtual CUPS printer doesn't help. Moreover after piping pdf through CUPS adobe reader doesn't see the glyph at all.

Comment: Have you tested the PDF produced by XeLaTeX. Are *all* the fonts embedded. Adobe Reader and `pdfinfo` can be helpful. Can you provide a bit more details about *looks the other way* on his machine. How do you detect a slightly deformed layout?

Comment: I have font awesome symbols, and on other machine the size of the symbols is changed: they are larger and overlap with other characters. After `prepress` of ps2pdf I'm sure that all fonts are embedded. I visited the guy again but he already left home. So I wait for tommorrow.

Comment: Unless "the printing guy" can show you a preflight report of Adobe Acrobat with _errors_ in the pdf, I would simply go to another "printing guy".

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134121/729.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps2pdf14 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress input.pdf output.pdf
```

solves the problem of the scaled font.