# Problems with font display under Adobe Reader

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdf, viewers, adobe

I am using the commercial fonts "Flexo" and "Brix Slab" with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{HVD Fonts - BrixSlab-Light.otf}
\setsansfont{Durotype - Flexo-Medium.otf}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\sffamily \blindtext
\end{document}
```

The generated PDFs look good with every PDF viewer except for Adobe Reader X and XI where the "Flexo" font is a mess.

[image: Display of MWE under Adobe Reader]

The output of "pdffonts" yields:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
YCEXOQ+BrixSlab-Light-Identity-H     CID Type 0C       yes yes yes      5  0
JAZBMS+Flexo-Medium-Identity-H       CID Type 0C       yes yes yes      7  0
```

The problem occurs under Linux (TeXLive) as well as under Windows (MiKTeX).

What is the problem?

Comment: It might be an instance of the problem discussed in [fontawesome icons are getting too big using XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134121/fontawesome-icons-are-getting-too-big-using-xelatex)

Comment: Ah, okay. This could be an explanation. Flexo – in contrast to Brix Slab – has indeed an UPM of 3333 according to FontForge. Thus it might be affected by this XeTeX bug.