# Where does the package fontspec look for OpenType fonts, especially FontAwesome.otf?

Tags: fonts, texlive, ubuntu, font-encodings, fontawesome

I have a supposedly trivial question and I'm having a hard time finding an answer.

How can I determine the directories where `fontspec` is looking for OTF files?

I want to edit `FontAwesome.otf` with fontforge following these instructions:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134244/76715

On an **Ubuntu 14.10** machine with **TeX Live 2014** installed I edited this font and saved a duplicate in the following directories because I found copies or links to `FontAwesome.otf`.

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public

/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public
```

After editing the corresponding cls file XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX still can't find the new font.

Comment: I changed `fontenc` to `fontspec`

Comment: Why don't you install it as a *system*  font? Fontawesystem is not especially linked to TeX.

Comment: I thought I did that by `sudo apt-get install fonts-font-awesome`. And I don't know why I have so many copies of this font. I messed up something.

Comment: @Patryk A solution may be to put your modified version of the font in a folder named ".fonts", in your home directory. This version will be loaded by `fontspec` instead of the ones in /usr.

Comment: @Jean-SébastienGosselin Thank you for advice. I created `~/.fonts` and copied the font into it. However it still cannot be found when I edit this line `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome-1000upm}`in the corresponding cls file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use `kpsewhich` to locate the specific file TeX is going to load.

For your specific question, `kpsewhich FontAwesome.otf` will tell you which copy of the font you need to modify.