# Problem in fixing the bug of FontAwesome when compiled by XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I have followed the instructions that is given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134244/23594) for *fontawesome icons that are too big using XeLaTeX*. I was able to use [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) and change the Em Size to 1000. I also used the following FontForge’s Python script to generate a new font:

```
import fontforge
font = fontforge.open("C:/Windows/Fonts/FontAwesome.otf")
font.em = 1000
font.generate("C:/Windows/Fonts/FontAwesome-1000upm.otf")
```

I then copied `FontAwesome-1000upm.otf` to my LaTeX project directory and also installed it in my Windows. I also added `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome-1000upm}` to the preamble of my document after `\usepackage{fontawesome}` but XeLaTeX complains that it cannot find the font.

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "FontAwesome-1000upm" cannot be found. For immediate help type H <return>. \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome-1000upm}
```

When I check `C:/Windows/Fonts`, I can only see `FontAwesome Regular`. However, the directory list shows something else:

```
C:\Windows\Fonts>dir fontawesome*
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B8DD-C28E

 Directory of C:\Windows\Fonts

05/05/2015  11:39 AM           101,524 FontAwesome-1000upm.otf
05/05/2015  11:39 AM           101,524 FontAwesome-1000upm_0.otf
04/17/2015  08:56 PM            93,888 FontAwesome.otf
04/17/2015  08:56 PM            93,888 FontAwesome_0.otf
04/17/2015  08:56 PM            93,888 FontAwesome_1.otf
04/17/2015  08:56 PM            93,888 FontAwesome_2.otf
```

Could someone help me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by passing the path as an option to `\newfontfamily`:

```
\newfontfamily{\FA}[Path = C:/Windows/Fonts/]{FontAwesome-1000upm}
```