# Similar package with fontawesome

Tags: pdf, fontawesome

Is there any other package similar to fontawesome? I ask that because i can not use fontawesome as it scales the icons in adobe reader X (I am using friggeri.cls). Same problem in this link:
[Friggeri resume - Very different rendering in different readers](http://tex.aspcode.net/view/635399273629833626212278/friggeri-resume-very-different-rendering-in-different-readers) . I coudnt find any solution with this so next choice is to find another pachage.

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-symbol

Answer (score 2):

As I answered for [Friggeri resume - Very different rendering in different readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121891/friggeri-resume-very-different-rendering-in-different-readers/238036#238036), this problem comes from a bug with the pdf engine of XeLaTex with the OTF font file format when it is at a particular resolution as discussed in http://typophile.com/node/46451.

As a workaround, you can download the latest FontAwesome package at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/, extract the content and copy the file named "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" in a sub-folder of your LaTex document location. Assuming the .ttf file has been saved in the sub-folder named "fonts" within your LaTex document location, FontAwesome can be loaded and used in LaTex manually like this,:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\FA}[Path = fonts/]{fontawesome-webfont}

\def\faLinux{{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}}
\def\faSE{{\FA\symbol{"F18D}}}
\def\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\def\github{{\FA\symbol{"F092}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Linux icon: \faLinux \\
StackExchange icon: \faSE \\
GitHub icon: \github \\
Skype icon: \faSkype

\end{document}
```

The oversized icon in Adobe Reader should be fixed. You can check out my GitHub where I exactly did this with the Friggeri template: https://github.com/jnsebgosselin/Curriculum-Vitae