# Linux fonts with several weights

Tags: fonts, linux

Identically to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113911/problem-while-compiling-friggeri-cv-template-with-fontspec-error-font-not-f), I'm trying to use the amazing [Frigerri CV template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv) on Linux Mint 17 (which is based on Ubuntu)

The answer there points to the `.cls` file. But the file mentions three *sans* fonts of different weights.

I know there are a few Linux fonts which match Helvetica very closely (e.g. [Nimbus Sans](http://typophile.com/node/49127)) but I can't work out how to get a light version and a bold version.

```
-\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
-\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
-\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}
```

How might I modify these lines to use Nimbus Sans with various weights?

OR

Are there any Linux *sans* fonts with several weights like this?

Comment: I'm confused. The answer and comments there do, indeed, discuss sans fonts of different weights. So doesn't that answer your question concerning '*sans* fonts with several weights'? Helvetica *is* sans. There are various Nimbus fonts. One is regularly used as a substitute for Times or Times New Roman i.e. *serif*. The TeX Gyre collection mentioned in the answer you linked to includes good substitutes for a range of serif and sans fonts. Anyway, please edit your question to clarify it. Right now I'm just really confused. The ADF collection includes several families with different weights.

Comment: Ooops. I meant `Nimbus Sans`, not `Nimbus`. Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question.

Comment: I am not sure now what you mean by a 'Linux font'. I had assumed you meant fonts typically or frequently packaged for GNU/Linux distros. However, Nimbus Sans is a commercial font as far as I can tell and would not be packaged as part of a distro unless the distro licensed the fonts, which would be unusual and is certainly not likely to include Mint. Do you *have* the fonts? If so, there is no reason you can't use them, but the fact you are using Linux Mint is irrelevant in that case.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to use a font with various weights you find online.

I've used [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-code-pro) as suggested by [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113911/problem-while-compiling-friggeri-cv-template-with-fontspec-error-font-not-f#comment251444_113912) under the question I linked to in the original post.

### Download the font

You should get a zip file with a load of `TTF` and/or `OTF` files. If `OTF` exists, use these for everything that follows ([here's why](https://superuser.com/questions/96390/difference-between-otf-open-type-or-ttf-true-type-font-formats)).

I got my font from SourceForge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecodepro.adobe/files/).

### Get the TTF/OTF files

Make a subdirectory called `fonts` inside the directory where `friggeri-cv.cls` is (or whatever class file you're using). Put all the ttf/otf files directly into this `fonts` directory.

### Make reference to the new fonts

Remove all lines referring to Helvetica Neue and add these lines in their place:

```
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[Path=fonts/]{SourceCodePro-Regular}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[Path=fonts/]{SourceCodePro-ExtraLight}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[Path=fonts/]{SourceCodePro-Bold}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor, Path=fonts/]{SourceCodePro-Light}
```

Then do `xelatex cv_10.tex` and the pdf file will render. (I happen to think Source Code Pro doesn't look too hot, but these instructions will work for other fonts you find.

Comment: OK. So is this answered now? That's not what I thought you were asking, but it is your question, after all!

Comment: Yes, it's answered. Thanks @cfr for all your input.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to indicate this. (I don't think you get reputation. Well, probably you get +2. But it helps show people which questions need answers and which do not.)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want serif fonts, since sans are already covered by the other question, you might like:

- [Baskervald ADF](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/baskervald/)
- [Venturis ADF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/venturisadf/doc/fonts/venturisadf/venturisadf.pdf)
- [Something else from the font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html)

Although these are LaTeX packages, many of these are available in opentype format so can be easily used with `fontspec`. Note that the font catalogue does not always show all of the fonts in a family. For example, it doesn't show the range of weights in Venturis which is why I linked to the package documentation in that case instead:

[image: Venturis ADF]

You can download Venturis ADF in truetype or opentype format from [Arkandis](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/tugfonts.htm) if your distro does not package them.