# Missing font for friggeri cv (despite installation)

Tags: fonts, errors, fontspec, windows, friggeri-cv

For my cv I'm using the friggeri-cv template, which was already was reason for serveral threads here.

The template is heavily build on HelveticaNeue, which is installed on my system (Win7/TeXnicCenter) and can be used in other programs like Open Office Writer and Microsoft Word.

When compiling with the original fonts I get following errors with an added suggestion to' ask someone for help!':

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! The font "Helvetica Neue LT Std 37" cannot be found.
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
```

Also tried the approach posted by Nils L of using standard fonts for testing purposes, which work fine. But as Helvetica Neue is installed on my system i would prefer to use it.

My best guess would be that the spelling needed for latex is somehow different as the one used in win7.

Has anybody experienced same issues and was able to solve it ?

I'm aware of [Problem while compiling friggeri CV template with: ' fontspec error: "font-not-found"'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113911/problem-while-compiling-friggeri-cv-template-with-fontspec-error-font-not-f) and was going to comment my issue there but apparently I'm lacking reputation.

Comment: When using system font names, you must use the form found in the "Font name" field in Windows Font Viewer when you open _an individual font_. On my Windows 7 system, "Helvetica Neue LT Std 37" is the name of a _Font Family_ which appears in Control Panel -> All Items -> Fonts, but it is not the name of an individual font. The two fonts in this family are named "HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin Cn". My guess would be, if you use this name instead, it will work.

Comment: Thanks Paul, finally it worked with Helvetica Neue. Now i just have to find the equivalents of Adrien fonts on my system. Where can i accept your answer ?

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked. I've just added a proper answer below—I waited to add it until I knew it was going to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using system font names, you must use the form found in the "Font name" field in Windows Font Viewer when you open *an individual font*. On my Windows 7 system, "Helvetica Neue LT Std 37" is the name of a *Font Family* which appears in `Control Panel > All Items > Fonts`, but it is not the name of an individual font. The fonts in this family are named "HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin Cn". If you use this name instead, it will work.

This has to do with how `fontspec` loads system fonts by name. You can also specify the font's filename. Sometimes this can be more convenient. So either of the `\setmainfont` lines in my short example code below will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin Cn} % by name, LuaLaTeX
%\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn}     % by name, XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn.otf}  % by filename, either engine

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

The selection by name for LuaLaTeX uses `luaotfload` for system fonts. Spaces and casing are insignificant with `luaotfload`. If you're using XeLaTeX, a different method is used for loading fonts, and a slightly different name is required (this time found using `Properties > Details > Title`). Selection by filename works with either engine.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: I had to change some of the fonts, because I couldn't find any equivalent Helvetica Neue on Windows. When compiling with XeLaTex/LuaLaTeX following error appears in the logfile:    "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/SourceSansPro-Light.otf(0)/m/it' undefined". Is it possible that Latex can't find the italic version of this font, despite it's being installed and used in other programs?

Comment: @user2878448 please take a look at the `fontspec` documentation. Under the section Font selection -> By file name it states: "Fonts selected by filename must include bold and italic variants explicitly."